# Inferring types and using type annotations when parsing a string to a number

Tags: rust, inferred-type

I'm trying to write a function that will parse float from given string. It should return error in case of wrong or negative value.

```
fn read_value(strvalue: &str) -> Result<f32, Error> {
    match FromStr::from_str(strvalue) {
        None => Err(Error::InvalidValue),
        Some(value) => if value >= 0.0 {Ok(value)} else {Err(Error::InvalidValue)}
    }
}
```

This code gives:

```
src/main.rs:50:27: 50:32 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
src/main.rs:50         Some(value) => if value >= 0.0 {Ok(value)} else {Err(Error::InvalidValue)}
```

The first point. This error seems strange to me because, if I understand correctly, type of `value` can be inferred automatically. From the result type the type of `value` must be `f32`.

The second question. How can I fix this error? Or more general - how to annotate types of expressions in Rust?

E.g. in Haskell I can write something like:

```
if (value :: f32) > 0.0 ...
```

Or put type annotation in pattern match::

```
Some(value :: f32) => ...
```

Comment: I certainly would expect the type inference to unify the return type (which has the `f32`) with the type of the expression `Ok(value)` and deduce that `value : f32`. Can you make sure that's really the issue by adding a type hint to the `from_str` call? I.e. `<f32 as FromStr>::from_str(strvalue)`? **Edit**: Yeah, that fixes it for me. Still no clue as to why, or whether that's the best solution, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: @delnan I think it's fine to post "partial" answers when the question is actually multiple questions.

Comment: This is got to be a bug. If I change the original code to be `if 0.0 <= value`, it compiles. I've filed [21634](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21634)

Comment: For the record, the `FromStr::from_str` has been changed to return a `Result<_, _>` instead of `Option<_>`. So if you try it on Rust master, keep this in mind.

Comment: And the fix ([21817](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21817)) is on its way to the master :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work around it, I'd suggest using the [`parse`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.parse) method with a type parameter. To specify a functions type parameter, instead of calling `foo()`, you call `foo::<types>()`:

```
fn read_value(strvalue: &str) -> Result<f32, u8> {
    match strvalue.parse::<f32>() {
        None => Err(1),
        Some(value) => if value >= 0.0 {Ok(value)} else {Err(2)}
    }
}
```

Another form that works without a type annotation (and hints that this might be a bug). This version uses a *match guard*:

```
fn read_value(strvalue: &str) -> Result<f32, u8> {
    match FromStr::from_str(strvalue) {
        None => Err(1),
        Some(value) if value >= 0.0 => Ok(value),
        _ => Err(2),
    }
}
```

And another using chained methods, representing it as a series of transforms:

```
fn read_value_chain(strvalue: &str) -> Result<f32, u8> {
    strvalue.parse()
        .ok_or(1)
        .and_then(|v: f32| if v > 0.0 { Ok(v) } else { Err(2) })
}
```